# Функция для синхронизации значений элементов input

Tags: javascript

На какую тему ориентирована данная задача?

Задайте тело одиночной функции f таким образом, чтобы значение `i2.value`
стало синхронизировано с `i1.value`, то есть, оно должно быть равно `i1.value` и в дальнейшем меняться при изменении `i1.value`.

i1 и i2 – input элементы.

**Ограничение1:** нельзя использовать глобальные переменные
**Ограничение2:** `i1.id` и `i2.id` неопределены, и их нельзя определять
**Ограничение3:** нельзя модифицировать свойства i1 и i2, кроме `value` и 
свойств, отвечающих за события (`onChange` и т.п.).

```
function f(i1,i2) // i1,i2 - input-элементы
{}
```

Comment: на события DOM и замыкания

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я как-раз еще ES6 не изучил, поэтому возможно мой вариант вам подойдет:

```js
'use strict';

function f(i1, i2) {

  function sync(event) {
    i2.value = event.target.value;
  }

  i1.addEventListener('input', sync);
}

f(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0], document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]);
```

```html
  <input>
  <input>
```

- По заданию у вас только односторонняя синхронизация(i2 равно i1). поэтому я так и сделал.

Comment: Синхронизация из второго поля в первое не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Здравствуйте! Это и не требовалось по заданию.

Comment: Эм.. Только я понимаю синхронизированность как двунаправленную связь?

Answer (score 5):

> нельзя модифицировать свойства i1 и i2, кроме value и свойств, отвечающих за события

Ну всё же написано в этой фразе. Надо подписаться на события и в их обработчике модифицировать `value`.

Например, при поддержке браузером ES6 можно сделать так:

```js
function f(i1, i2) {
  const i = [i1, i2];
  
  for (let q=0; q<2; ++q) {
    i[q].addEventListener('input', e => i[q^1].value = e.target.value);
  }
}

f(document.querySelector('input'), document.querySelector('input+input'));
```

```html
<input> <input>
```

Comment: А можно это без ES6 реализовать? Я просто пока учусь, и не совсем понимаю как это сделать (

Comment: @Ruslan Смотрите мой ответ.

Comment: Можно f(i1, i2) -> f(...args). избавимся тогда от const i = [i1, i2];

Comment: В данной конкретной задаче, намного более читамыми были бы 2 вызова addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

for (let input of inputs) {
  input.oninput = function(e) {
    var event = new CustomEvent('sync', {
      detail: input.value
    })
    for (let mInput of inputs) {
      mInput.dispatchEvent(event)
    }
  }

  input.addEventListener('sync', function(e) {
    input.value = e.detail
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```